# API C# - Atualização

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Criei uma API usando entity Framework, a conexão esta ok, porem, quando atualizo os dados no banco de dados, qlqr um dos campos, no Json na API não aparece a mudança.

Como resolver esse tipo de atualização?

Comment: faltam informações para resolver seu problema, poste o código que está usando para receber do banco, talvez o problema estejá lá

Comment: Oii, é que criei tudo no controller, no modo automático.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verificar se o objeto que você retorna para API é o mesmo que você atualizou.

Caso esteja recuperando o objeto do banco após a atualização, tenta usar o AsNoTracking na consulta para não pergar as informações que estão em cache.